# What is C(argument) in documentation

Tags: ansible

Recently I have been reviewing a lot of Ansible modules(code) and I have come across some with this strange nomenclature in the documentation section when referring to arguments such as the examples ([F5 modules](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.5.0rc3/lib/ansible/modules/network/f5/bigip_node.py)) below:

> specified, the default of **C(round-robin)** will be used

or this

> If this value is an IP address, and the **C(type)** is **C(tcp)** (the
>   default),
>           then a **C(port)** number must be specified.

What is the **C** and is it required when documenting your code? As I said not all of the modules have in them.

Comment: My guess would be that `C(...)` is supposed to be rendered in a `code` font, but instead it just shows the markup.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this in [`ansible.docs-1.7.pdf`](http://people.ds.cam.ac.uk/jw35/docs/ansible/ansible-docs-1.7.pdf)<sup>1)</sup>, page 545:

> The `description`, and `notes` fields support formatting with some
>   special macros.
>
> These formatting functions are `U()`, `M()`, `I()`, and `C()` for URL,
>   module, italic, and constant-width respectively. It is suggested to
>   use `C()` for file and option names, and `I()` when referencing
>   parameters; module names should be specifies as `M(module)`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> This seems to be somewhat dated, but should still be valid. The same can also be found in the [latest online documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_documenting.html#formatting-options).